# high disk watermark [90%] exceeded in JHipster Spring Boot app

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, jhipster

In every 30s I get:

```
[anagement][T#2]] o.e.cluster.routing.allocation.decider   : [Colonel] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [eDGCiPerSn-80duo6JXd5A][Colonel][/home/.../target/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 44gb[6%], shards will be relocated away from this node
```

I found this:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/disk-allocator.html
but how can I apply it in Spring Boot app?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the reference provided by you, the disk allocator stands on:

- Modules » Cluster » Disk-based Shard Allocation

So you have to deploy elastic on a cluster configuration and the cluster will be responsible by the configuration you will set were/when to switch the service to. In your case it will switch it due to low disk space to another node with available disk space.

Then on your app you will configure the VIP of the cluster on Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

JHipster has embeded Elasticsearch so I figured out to add to application-dev.yml file:

```
data:
        elasticsearch:
            properties:   
                cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high: 95%
```